# Prisma 2.0 Beta Deploy

Tags: graphql, prisma

Trying to deploy an Node/Apollo-Server/Prisma 2.0 Beta app to heroku and receiving this error

Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.

Is there a script I should run pre build? npx prisma generate? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating the client with `npx prisma generate` from a Heroku postbuild hook? (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps).

Comment: I have tried the postbuild hook in my package.json but it didn't seem to work. I'll definitely give it a try again I could be implementing it wrong. I'm also going to try to run npx prisma generate command with heroku run. I'll try to report back any insight. Thank you.

Comment: I normally like to run the `prisma generate` command "preinstall" rather than "postbuild." I'd play around with these. One of them must work!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165511/how-to-use-prisma-2-cli-on-heroku/65173592#65173592