# How to use Prisma 2 CLI on Heroku

Tags: heroku, nestjs, prisma, heroku-cli

I have deployed NestJs application on Heroku which uses Prisma 2, but when I run the command
`npx prisma --version` on heroku bash I get `Prisma CLI version: prisma/1.34.10 (linux-x64) node-v14.15.0` but I have installed prisma 2.11.0, I want to use Prisma 2 cli to introspect my existing database, and run prisma generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to introspect my existing database and run prisma generate by adding heroku-postbuild command on my package.json in scripts section as show below:

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "heroku-postbuild": "prisma introspect && prisma generate"
   }
}
```

Now when I push to heroku the `heroku-postbuild` command will be executed.

**Note**: By default, Heroku after installing all dependencies listed in package.json under dependencies and devDependencies will strip out (Pruning devDependencies) the packages declared under devDependencies before deploying the application.

`heroku-postbuild` runs after Heroku installs dependencies, but before Heroku prunes and caches dependencies. Thus why the specified prisma introspect && prisma generate will use the prisma cli specified on package.json.

**Note:** To skip the pruning step of devDependencies set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to false as shown below, so that we can access packages declared under devDependencies at runtime:

`heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`

After setting NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to false now if we run `npx prisma --version` we will get the installed version from package.json

For more information please visit : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-behavior