# Bundling the Prisma Client together with a SvelteKit build

Tags: node.js, gitlab, svelte, prisma, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit and the Typescript package Prisma Client together. Prisma Client is a dependency that has to be generated before the app can run. Generating the Prisma Client and then running the development version with `npm run dev` works.

But when I build with `npm run build`, I cannot run the app with `node` without doing another `npm install` for the Prisma Client with `npx prisma generate`.

I'm using the following (probably very verbose) Gitlab `gitlab-ci.yaml` job script to do an extra `npm install` step:

```yaml
deploy:
  image: alpine
  before_script:
  - apk update && apk add openssh-client rsync
  script:
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
  - ssh-keyscan -H $WEB_SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - rsync -chavzP --stats . "root@$WEB_SERVER_IP:~/dsp-app"     
  - ssh root@$WEB_SERVER_IP "cd $FOLDER; npm install"
  - ssh root@$WEB_SERVER_IP "cd $FOLDER; npx prisma generate --schema src/lib/backend/prisma/schema.prisma"
  - ssh root@$WEB_SERVER_IP "cd $FOLDER; npm run build"
  - ssh root@$WEB_SERVER_IP "cd $FOLDER; pm2 delete index 2> /dev/null || true"
  - ssh root@$WEB_SERVER_IP "cd $FOLDER; pm2 startup"
  - ssh root@$WEB_SERVER_IP "cd $FOLDER; pm2 start -f build/index.js  --watch"
  - ssh root@$WEB_SERVER_IP "cd $FOLDER; pm2 save"
```

The `npm install` step seems to be redundant, however. Is there a way to *bundle the Prisma Client* with `npm build` (and then transfer the build to the server), so I don't have to do another `npm install` on the production server which runs `node`?

This question is similar to [Prisma 2.0 Beta Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068802/prisma-2-0-beta-deploy) but answer there didn't show how to do this.